Is this flyback topology?
In below circuit transformer output is rectified and going to load.
Many smps circuits doesn't even have that L1 inductor. Where can I get more material to read on this?
source:
https://electrobuff.blogspot.com/2024/02/uc3842-switching-power-supply-for.html


Not sure this flyback power supply has ever been assembled and I would be cautious before plugging it. I don't see a compensation for the TL431 (a cap. between K and REF is missing), an extra 1-mA bias is also missing and the 56-kOhm/2-W resistance is likely to fry in high-line operation. Also, I would recommend to simply ground the FB and connect the COMP pin to VREF via a 10-k resistance plus a small 1-nF capacitor from COMP to GND, close to the controller pins. I concur with one of the answers, inductor L1 shall not be connected, at least not in this way.

it seems you are looking in the wrong places for schematics. If you want to build a switch-mode power supply based on an IC, I'd recommend going to one of the manufacturers of such ICs (TI.com, analog.com, microchip.com, diodes.com,…), picking one that fulfills your needs (in this case "off-line switcher", ideally "with asynchronous" or "synchronous" "rectification"). Also, no. Please don't start your journey into switch mode supplies by building one that plugs into your grid. That's a sure way to smoke, possibly to electrocution or building fires. There's literally no reason to build this…

… yourself; commercially available power supplies will be cheaper and better than what you can build yourself, by far, and most importantly, they don't kill you. This will kill you. There's many other electronics projects you might want to tackle!

Most probably flyback due to snubber configuration, but without dot notation on the transformer, this isn't guaranteed. As you say, an output inductor is strange here would be indicative of a forward topology.

It must be a flyback topology since in core isn’t applied some demagnetisation feature.
Also, the 45 turns primary at Vin=230V would cause too much magnetising current in forward topology.
In flyback the L1 makes no sense and should be avoided.

C11-R14 provides some clamping; though it's unclear if it would be enough for a given transformer's reset phase. The transformer having absolutely no specs is the most damning.
